# Bash Loop Help (want to echo aa, bb, cc)

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

Loop logic always confuses me, this is probably a simple solution. My current loop:

```
for i in a b; do for j in a b; do echo $i$j; done; done
```

This loop prints the following output:

```
 aa
 ab
 ba
 bb
```

I would like for it to only print:

```
 aa
 bb
```

I just want it to match up the first two letters, then the second two letters and so on. Eventually I want to expand this over files in two different directories. So I want to print the first file name in dir1, then the first in dir2. Then the 2nd in dir1 and the 2nd in dir2. Just trying to simplify that and understand the logic first.

Comment: In general, are the pairs of characters always the same? If so, a single loop with `echo "$i$i"` would be the obvious solution.

Comment: Well I want to expand this over files in two different directories. So I want to print the first file name in dir1, then the first in dir2. Then the 2nd in dir1 and the 2nd in dir2. Just trying to simplify that.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add the details from your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using arrays to solve your problem:

```
dir1_files=( dir1/* )
dir2_files=( dir2/* )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#dir1_files[@]}; ++i )); do
    echo "${dir1_files[i]} ${dir2_files[i]}" 
done
```

This assumes that the number of files in each directory is the same.

Comment: Thank you, this is most along the lines I was looking for. Also helps my secondary approach to echoing file names.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that they're the same?

```
for i in a b; do 
  for j in a b; do 
    if [[ "$i" = "$j" ]]; then
      echo $i$j
    fi
  done
done
```

Or:

```
for i in a b; do for j in a b; do [[ "$i" = "$j" ]] && echo $i$j; done; done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also another solution to my initial question.